Local Notification doesn't work when App is launched from Xcode, but works when phone is restarted and App is launched locally
I wrote a simple app which has the goal of triggering a local notification (banner style, like a push notification) when the user clicks a button.
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                sendNotification()
            }) {
                Text("Send Notification")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            requestNotificationPermission()
        }
    }
}

func requestNotificationPermission() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Notification permission error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func sendNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Hello!"
    content.body = "This is a notification from your app."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Notification error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

When I build and run my app from Xcode and the click the button, nothing happens. Even if I close the app and restart it locally, nothing happens again... HOWEVER, if I restart the phone completely and then launch the app, the button works as intended and the local notification appears!
This is extremely aggravating to my development process, does anyone know why the app isn't working when I launch it from Xcode? FWIW it doesn't work AT ALL on the simulator, even if I restart the simulator and launch it "locally" like I do on my real device.
My real device is an iPhone XS running iOS 18 DB1, the simulator is an iPhone 15 running iOS 17.5

A local notification should not, by default, appear as a banner when the app that requested the notification is running. I'm surprised you ever see the banner.

Oh man. That's interesting. Let me try to change the timer to like 10 seconds and see if it works when I exit the app.

Thanks @matt, you were right. I wonder why it "works" (incorrectly) when the phone is freshly rebooted... Anyway, it works now with a timer of 10 seconds and me exiting the app from the foreground :)

you need to customize code in app delegate notification centre delegate to allow banner to appear even when app is in foreground and active

Does this answer your question? VisionOS send notification
